# how to deactivate compressor in django-redis?

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

I am using django-redis in django and want to turn off compressor. there are several options to set various types of compressors like zlib, lzma, etc. but not no compressor.

Answer (score 0):

From django-redis [readme](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis)

> django-redis comes with compression support out of the box, **but is
> deactivated by default**. You can activate it setting up a concrete
> backend:

Comment: But I see something like this in redis
�� �u_456�.
 while i set u_456 as value

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and my mistake was it is not about compressor but serializer.
So adding
"SERIALIZER": "django_redis.serializers.json.JSONSerializer",
to
"OPTIONS"
fixes the problem.